# Изменение порядка следования колонок в Datatables по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Здравствуйте. Использую плагин [datables](https://datatables.net/) для верстки таблицы. В API плагина есть свойство [ColReorder](https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/), включающее возможность изменения порядка следования колонок. Имеется также метод [colReorder.order()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/colReorder.order()), который может по клику менять порядок колонок согласно заранее установленным индексам в массиве:

```
$('#reverse').click( function (e) {
  table.colReorder.order( [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 ] );
});
```

Задача в том, чтобы сделать возможность изменять порядок следования колонок на кнопки "вперед" / "назад", т.е. по клику необходимо каким-то образом менять местами эти индексы в массиве. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
      colReorder: true,
      ordering: false,
      bFilter: false,
      bLengthChange: false,
      bInfo: false,
      bPaginate: false,
      autoWidth: false,
      fixedHeader: {
          header: true,
          footer: true
      }
    });
} );
```

```css
.btns-block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.13/cr-1.3.2/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/r-2.1.1/datatables.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.13/cr-1.3.2/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/r-2.1.1/rr-1.2.0/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Airi Satou</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009/09/15</td>
          <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Sonya Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008/12/13</td>
          <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jena Gaines</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2008/12/19</td>
          <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
          <td>Support Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2013/03/03</td>
          <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Charde Marshall</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2008/10/16</td>
          <td>$470,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2012/12/18</td>
          <td>$313,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>2010/03/17</td>
          <td>$385,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Michael Silva</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2012/11/27</td>
          <td>$198,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Paul Byrd</td>
          <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2010/06/09</td>
          <td>$725,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Gloria Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2009/04/10</td>
          <td>$237,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2012/10/13</td>
          <td>$132,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Dai Rios</td>
          <td>Personnel Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>2012/09/26</td>
          <td>$217,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
          <td>Development Lead</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2011/09/03</td>
          <td>$345,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Yuri Berry</td>
          <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>2009/06/25</td>
          <td>$675,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
          <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2011/12/12</td>
          <td>$106,450</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2010/09/20</td>
          <td>$85,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
          <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/10/09</td>
          <td>$1,200,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>2010/12/22</td>
          <td>$92,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2010/11/14</td>
          <td>$357,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2011/06/07</td>
          <td>$206,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Fiona Green</td>
          <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>2010/03/11</td>
          <td>$850,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Shou Itou</td>
          <td>Regional Marketing</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>2011/08/14</td>
          <td>$163,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Michelle House</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2011/06/02</td>
          <td>$95,400</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Suki Burks</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2009/10/22</td>
          <td>$114,500</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="btns-block">
  <a class="btn-prev" href="#close">Prev</a>
  <a class="btn-next" href="#close">Next</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```js
var index = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  colReorder: true,
  ordering: false,
  bFilter: false,
  bLengthChange: false,
  bInfo: false,
  bPaginate: false,
  autoWidth: false,
  fixedHeader: {
      header: true,
      footer: true
  }
});

$('.btn-next').click(function() {
  index.push(index.shift());
  table.colReorder.order( index );
  index = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
});

$('.btn-prev').click(function() {
  index.splice(0, 0, index.splice(index.length - 1, 1)[0]);
  table.colReorder.order( index );
  index = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
});
```

```css
.btns-block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.13/cr-1.3.2/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/r-2.1.1/datatables.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.13/cr-1.3.2/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/r-2.1.1/rr-1.2.0/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Airi Satou</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009/09/15</td>
          <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Sonya Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008/12/13</td>
          <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jena Gaines</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2008/12/19</td>
          <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
          <td>Support Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2013/03/03</td>
          <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Charde Marshall</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2008/10/16</td>
          <td>$470,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2012/12/18</td>
          <td>$313,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>2010/03/17</td>
          <td>$385,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Michael Silva</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2012/11/27</td>
          <td>$198,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Paul Byrd</td>
          <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2010/06/09</td>
          <td>$725,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Gloria Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2009/04/10</td>
          <td>$237,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2012/10/13</td>
          <td>$132,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Dai Rios</td>
          <td>Personnel Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>2012/09/26</td>
          <td>$217,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
          <td>Development Lead</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2011/09/03</td>
          <td>$345,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Yuri Berry</td>
          <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>2009/06/25</td>
          <td>$675,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
          <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2011/12/12</td>
          <td>$106,450</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2010/09/20</td>
          <td>$85,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
          <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/10/09</td>
          <td>$1,200,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>2010/12/22</td>
          <td>$92,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2010/11/14</td>
          <td>$357,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2011/06/07</td>
          <td>$206,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Fiona Green</td>
          <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>2010/03/11</td>
          <td>$850,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Shou Itou</td>
          <td>Regional Marketing</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>2011/08/14</td>
          <td>$163,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Michelle House</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2011/06/02</td>
          <td>$95,400</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Suki Burks</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2009/10/22</td>
          <td>$114,500</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="btns-block">
  <a class="btn-prev" href="#close">Prev</a>
  <a class="btn-next" href="#close">Next</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не совсем Сейчас местами меняются только первая и последняя колонки, нужно чтобы по клику, например вправо произошло следующее: колонка Name с индексом `[0]` переместилась в конец массива `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0]`, повторное нажатие и массив принимает следующий вид: `[2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1]` и так далее.

Comment: @Игорь Поправил ответ.

Comment: не могу понять, в чем проблема? При первом клике все происходит по необходимому сценарию, массив преобразуется из `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` в `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0]`, зато следующий клик приводит к виду `[3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2]` и после этого все ломается...

Comment: http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/qrZQrE?editors=1010 - для наглядности

Comment: @Игорь Я понял почему так происходит)) После того, как нажимается кнопка назад или вперед, то индексу `0` присваивается либо `Name`, либо `Position`, то есть переменную `index` нужно сбрасывать в исходное состояние. Я сейчас снова отредактирую ответ, он теперь будет работать как вы хотите.

Comment: благодарю вас) Только что выяснил, что если прописывать строку `var index = [0,1,2,3,4,5];` в функциях с кликами по кнопкам, то все работает корректно)

Comment: @Игорь но без `var` - переменная уже объявлена.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте!

Берем начальный массив `var order = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]`.
Как я понимаю вам нужно при нажатие кнопки `next`, чтобы массив стал таким `var order = [ 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]` и т.д.
Это можно реализовать так - при нажатие кнопки удаляем последний элемент и добавляем в начало массива.

```
order.unshift(order.pop());
```

Затем уже можно использовать это массив:

```
table.colReorder.order( order );
```

Ну для кнопки назад можно сделать по аналогий(удаляем из начала массива и добавляем в конец).

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ, @qpeela. Прошу прощения за "размытость" задачи, необходимо по клику на `next` перемещать первый эл-т массива в его конец, т.е. он примет следующий вид: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0]`. В целом мысль вашу услышал, ситуацию в корне не меняет, спасибо)